# Facebook Marketing API - adding ProductCatalog

Tags: php, facebook, curl, facebook-php-sdk

I need help. I use developer app where I try add ProductCatalog to Business Manager. Earlier I add Multi Product and is it ok.

```
$catalog = new ProductCatalog(null,'<BUSINESS_ID>');
$catalog->setData(array(
    ProductCatalogFields::NAME => 'test',
));
$catalog->save();
```

I get error

> (#275) Ad account cannot be determined for this request

When I try

```
$request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'POST', '/<BUSINESS_ID>/product_catalogs',array('name'=>'test') );
$response = $request->execute();
```

I get

> (#275) Ad account cannot be determined for this request

What happened? ProductCatalog need AdAcoountID? I add to app settings all adaccounts ids. Where I must add this in code. I have the newest API.

Comment: Maybe this can help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29278909/how-to-get-a-listing-of-product-catalogs-from-a-business-manager-with-developmen

Answer (score 3):

What is the level of Ads API access that the app you use has? As described [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/access) there are different levels. Since Product Catalogs uses Business Manager, [you need](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/access#limits) to have Marketing API Access with the "Standard" level.

If your app is still on "Development" or "Basic" access, see the above mentioned documentation to read how you can apply for higher access.

You can see what level of access you have by going to you App Dashboard --> "Status and Review", create a new submission for review and see which permissions are available.

Comment: Shouldn't you be able to test it on a development level first, before applying for me? The application rules require information that cannot exist on an initial project level.

Comment: In this case, it is not possible to test the API, unless you have been granted access. See also the page about System Users: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/businessmanager/systemuser/v2.3 and the red notice about permission.