# How to get a listing of product catalogs from a business manager with development access?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I have a developer account and have created an application in development mode, just for testing purposes. I have also created a business manager at `business.facebook.com`, and added my test app to it. I have an ad account as well, which is added into the business manager. I also added the ad account ID to my application under the `Advanced --> Advertising Accounts --> Authorized accounts`.

However, when I use the Facebook Graph API Explorer, and set it to use the application I created, then make a call to `/v2.3/[BUSINESS_ID]/product_catalogs`, I get the following error:

```
"message": "(#275) Ad account cannot be determined for this request",
```

If I call the ad account directly, at `/v2.3/act_[adaccountId]`, i can see the ad account information just fine.

If I create a product catalog myself in business manager, then call the endpoint for details on that product catalog at `/v2.3/[product_catalog_id]`, i get the following:

```
"message": "(#200) The app is not whitelisted to use this API",
```

If i am accessing catalogs that i am the admin for, and for apps that i am the admin for, and am using development access, why would it need to be whitelisted?

Comment: AFAIK, ads API needs whitelisting of your app in any case, even if you are still in development stage – you need to get your app whitelisted before you can start.

Comment: @CBroe how do I go about doing that? I only have found information on applying for basic or standard access

Comment: I'd also love to know how to link an app

Comment: me too :/ @CBroe? any hints? how you whitelist the api??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue here is as you said, your application is in the Development Tier for the Ads API. There are 3 tiers to the Ads API:

1. Development Tier
2. Basic Tier
3. Standard Tier

All of which are documented in the [Marketing API Access Levels](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/access) documentation. In order to access any part of the Business Manager API your application will need to have access to the Standard Tier.

I would recommend that you follow the steps in the documentation to move up the levels and when you believe you are ready, you can apply for [Standard Tier Access](https://www.facebook.com/business/standardadsapi)

Comment: I find it hard to swallow that the business manager API cannot be used with the "Development" tier for whitelisted apps, and that instead you would need to have "Standard" access. Is this really the case? If so, how are you supposed to test out various endpoints and get approved for "basic" tier and then "standard" tier?